# Como evitar que uma aplicação que roda em background seja parada pelo usuário?

Tags: java, android, android-service

Por exemplo uma aplicação que precise das cordenadas do aparelho de 30 em 30 segundos e que rode em background e, o usuário não pode forçar sua parada manualmente.

Answer (score 2):

Pelo que entendi você quer desenvolver um serviço "zumbi" que vai funcionar independente do aplicativo. Eu não aconselhavél, você tem que pensar na vida útil da bateria, ainda mais usando o GPS. Se não for um aplicativo de uso interno de uma empresa, você tem chance de ter um alto nível de rejeição do usuário.

Mas...

Pra isso você vai precisar de um BroadcastReceiver:

No manifest:

```
<receiver
            android:name=".services.ReceiverCall"
            android:enabled="true"
            android:exported="false" >

            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="SEU PACOTE.service.broadcast" />
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
            </intent-filter>

        </receiver>
```

O broadcast:

public class ReceiverCall extends BroadcastReceiver {
    public ReceiverCall() {
    }

```
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            context.startService(new Intent(context, SEU_SERVICE.class));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

O jeito seria criar uma espécie de "período de execução de um serviço" com um AlarmManager e schedule. Não tem como evitar que o usuário pare um serviço, pois existem diversas formas de parar um serviço. É melhor você trabalhar em como re-executar seu serviço.

Com o `onStartCommand()`, o serviço retorna um inteiro que define o comportamento de reinicialização, no caso de o serviço seja encerrado pela plataforma Android.

Com essas constantes você pode "controlar" seus processos de serviço e retornar seus padrões:

- `Service.START_STICKY`
- `Service.START_NOT_STICKY`
- `Service.START_REDELIVER_INTENT`

[LEIA MAIS AQUI](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidServices/article.html)

Comment: Se o usuário parar o aplicativo é feito um kill -9 no processo e isso não dá chance de executar nenhum código de finalização. E por ser no processo qualquer agendamento feito no AlarmManager por esse processo vai embora junto.

Comment: @Piovezan, você está errado, uma vez que o próprio sistema pode ser direcionado a reiniciar o serviço. Isso é possível.

Comment: Olhando melhor [essa questão](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9093271/start-sticky-and-start-not-sticky), eu posso estar errado mesmo. Com as constantes citadas pode funcionar.

Comment: Na verdade se o usuário fizer *force stop* (no gerenciador de aplicativos > aplicativo > forçar parada) o serviço não é reiniciado nem com as constantes citadas, até que o usuário inicie o aplicativo novamente pelo ícone do launcher. Pelo menos e o que diz [essa resposta](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12672438/start-service-after-force-stop) e também [aqui](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=63618). Alarmes também não voltam. Errei o motivo mas o comportamento é como falei.

Answer (score 0):

Na verdade resolvi meu problema utilizando Services, colocando minha aplicação para ter nível de acesso de administrador e iniciando um novo serviço quando o usuário detruir a aplicação no método onDestroy do service.